# Cannot read property Length of InnerHTML and div id

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

This is the text to be checked:

```
<div id="List1" style="display:none">
   VIDEO 1</br>
   VIDEO 2</br>
   VIDEO 3</br>
</div>
```

This is the Javascript code:

```
var div = document.getElementById("List"+id); //id is a random number

if(div.innerHTML != "") // <-- this gives an error.
{
    document.getElementById("List"+id).style.display = "block";
}
```

When the debugger reads: if (div.innerHTML != ""), it gives this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Length' of undefined.

I want to check if one of the List is empty/not set/not existing.

Comment: u are having only one id above and u are checking it for random div id's its not good.

Comment: @ameyarote Yes.. but what do I have to do? How do I check if a div exist in Javascript?

Comment: If u  are creating random div's please give them counter so that u will have number of generated div's. it's not advisable to check if div exist or not.

Comment: Are you sure debugger complains about _property 'Length'_?

Comment: finally got the solution?

Comment: @SalmanA Oops, I don't think so, let me check it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Oned Zair, by following,

```
var myElem = document.getElementById('myElementId');
if (myElem == null) alert('does not exist!');
```

or

```
$(id).length > 0
```

you can check `div` exist or not.

Comment: Thank you man, but I have got strange results... for div id="List1" it is not null, but div id="List2" and "List3" which is almost the same, has been recognized as null, I have opened a new topic/question about it.

Comment: you can open new question for doubts.

Answer (score 2):

The `i` in innerHTML needs to be lowercase. Change `InnerHTML` to `innerHTML` .  It would also be prudent to check that the div exists in the conditional.

```
if(div && div.innerHTML != "")
{
    document.getElementById("List"+id).style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: Additionally add a check for div itself: `if (div && div.innerHTML != ""){...}`

Comment: Oke changed it to innerHTML

Comment: @OnedZair Excellent, did that fix this problem?

Comment: @KevinBowersox I want to check if a div exist... but I don't know how

Answer (score 0):

There is wrong syntax of innerHTML please change it to this code,....

if(document.getElementById("List"+id).innerHTML != "") 
{
    document.getElementById("List"+id).style.display = "block";
}